# How to select two last year in more actual year

Tags: sql, dateadd, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to know how we can select the two last year in more the current year.

For example, If I have a table like it :

```
id     date_enter      cost


1      19/09/2019    400$

1      20/09/2020    402$
     
1      19/04/2021   450$

1      19/09/2018    500$

1      05/03/2019    600$
    
1      19/09/2015    400$
```

Then I want it :

```
id     date_enter      cost

1      19/09/2019    400$

1      20/09/2020    402$
    
1      19/04/2021   450$

1      05/03/2019    600$
```

I tried to use dateadd like it :

```
date_enter>=DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE())
```

But I just  got the 2 last year since now,  I would like to got 2019, 2020 and 2021

thanks

Comment: `-3` instead of `-2`? And possibly cast the result of `dateadd()` (or `getdate()`) to a `date` to get rid of the hour, etc.  portion the `datetime` `getdate()` returns has.

Comment: no because I will get 2018 and I don't want,

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Or something else?

Comment: I'm using snowflake SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get data from January 1, 2019 (i.e. all the data from 2019, 2020, and 2021). Use `DATE_FROM_PARTS` to construct that date.

```
select * 
from mytable
where date_enter >= date_from_parts(year(current_date) - 2, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs you'll need to get all dates in the range 2 years back from TODAY, including everything after beginning of those first year (in the example after 2019-01-01).

Then I'll suggest using the YEAR function to compare after substracting the 2 years.

```
WHERE YEAR([Date]) >= YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()))
```

Quick example:

```
DECLARE @tblDates TABLE
(
    [Date] DATE
)

INSERT INTO @tblDates ([Date]) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'19/09/2019',103)
INSERT INTO @tblDates ([Date]) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'20/09/2020',103)
INSERT INTO @tblDates ([Date]) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'19/04/2021',103)
INSERT INTO @tblDates ([Date]) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'19/09/2018',103)
INSERT INTO @tblDates ([Date]) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'05/03/2019',103)
INSERT INTO @tblDates ([Date]) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,'19/09/2015',103)

SELECT * FROM @tblDates
WHERE YEAR([Date]) >= YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()))
```